# Laravel - pass variable to function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm creating a querys for database:

```
        $test_2_lowest = TestsCorrect
        ::join('results', 'tests_correct.id', '=', 'results.test_result_id')
        ->where([
            ['results.user_id', '=', $user_id],
            ['results.test_id', '=', '2'], // <----
        ])->min('correct');
```

and the only one changeable digit here is **'2'**.
I want to pass this as a variable somehow, that i doesnt have to declare multiple variables to get a score from different tests.

I tried form with input name which value is a digit:

```
<form action="{{route('results')}}" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="test_id" value="3"/>

<button type="submit">Send</button></form>
```

and function

```
    public function results(Request $test_id)
{
    $test_2_lowest = TestsCorrect
        ::join('results', 'tests_correct.id', '=', 'results.test_result_id')
        ->where([
            ['results.user_id', '=', $user_id],
            ['results.test_id', '=', $test_id->input('test_id');],
        ])->min('correct');
}
```

But it doesnt work :(

Comment: Remove `;` from array, it's a syntax error. Also read [mcve] and __explain__ your "doesn't work".

Comment: That ; wasn't actually in code, my bad with pasting it here, "doesnt work" meant "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" and the reson for that was that i had method="post", should be method="put"

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of clean syntax here

```
public function results(Request $request)
{
  $test_2_lowest = TestsCorrect::join('results', 'tests_correct.id', '=', 'results.test_result_id')
         ->where('results.user_id', '=', $user_id)
         ->where('results.test_id', '=', $request->get('test_id')),
  ])->min('correct');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but main reason was method="post", should be method="put"